# Problema con java -jar y parámetros

Tags: java, cmd, jar

Estoy intentando crear un acceso directo a un -jar que he creado pero no es capaz de ejecutarlo con doble click en cambio si ejecuto la sentencia desde un cmd si que a ejecuta.

Pantalla y comando del acceso directo:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Administrador.WIN-FO2VR137M84\Desktop\ETIQ\imp_etiquetas.jar" 908510.TXT 908510 0000500112 20000066 1 20 1 192.168.1.201
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego desde CMD si que ejecuta correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué pasa al ejecutar el acceso directo? ¿Sería posible que se esté ejecutando pero que acabe tan rápido que no veas la pantalla? En todo caso para estas cosas yo suelo usar un `.bat` (y luego, si acaso, acceso directo al `.bat`)

Comment: Segun el contenido de tu imagen tu acceso directo va a la carpeta bin del JRE,no deberiar ser simplemente la ubicacion del JAR.?

Answer (score 1):

Crea un fichero .bat con esa linea de comando y creas el acceso directo de ese .bat

Crea un fichero de texto nuevo, añade en ese fichero la linea de comando que has puesto `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Administrador.WIN-FO2VR137M84\Desktop\ETIQ\imp_etiquetas.jar" 908510.TXT 908510 0000500112 20000066 1 20 1 192.168.1.201`
y guarda el fichero como un txt. Después renombra el fichero y cambia la extensión por **.bat** y ya tendrás un ejecutable que realizara el comando como si lo lanzases desde consola.

Si por algún casual estas haciéndolo desde linux, el fichero sera **.sh** y la ruta cambiara un poco en la forma de escribirla.

Te recomiendo que añadas a tu PATH la ubicación del directorio de JAVA para así no tener que escribir toda la ruta de java y así el comando se reduciría a 
`java -jar "C:\Users\Administrador.WIN-FO2VR137M84\Desktop\ETIQ\imp_etiquetas.jar" 908510.TXT 908510 0000500112 20000066 1 20 1 192.168.1.201`

Ultima recomendación: Si pones este fichero donde tienes el fichero **.jar** reducirá aun más el comando.
`java -jar imp_etiquetas.jar 908510.TXT 908510 0000500112 20000066 1 20 1 192.168.1.201`

Comment: Hola Cadeq, estaría bien que en tu respuesta explicaras el proceso de realización. Esta pregunta y tu respuesta puede ser útil para visitantes en busca de información. y pueden no saber que es un `.bat`. Quizás [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) te ayude